# MySql in Bash: Show only errors

Tags: linux, mysql, rhel5

Let me first start off by saying I am not an experienced linux user.

I am trying to debug a mysql script in linux, however, my issue is that most of the queries are successful so I can not see the error messages because they scroll off the screen. I am executing the queries from a large file using the \. command.

I was wondering if there was a way to show ONLY the error messages when I exececute the sql file. Right now it is showing both error messages and Query OK,....

I don't really care about the queries that are ok, just the errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention much about HOW you use it; but if the "scrolling off the screen" is the problem at hand: capture ALL output in a file.

```
<command> | tee output 2>&1
```

Comment: when I did: bash> mysql | tee output 2>&1     Nothing happened
when I did mysql> \\. myfile.sql | tee output 2>&1    I got an error

Comment: something like this:    **mysql --batch  -e 'SHOW TABLES'; | tee output 2>&1**.  Also please mention WHAT error you're getting; with the info provided it's hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run mysql in batch mode (mysql -B), that makes it not give *any* output besides errors, not even a prompt.